# Add New Button apart from Previous and Next in jquery steps

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I want to add a new button called "Save" apart from the Previous and Next buttons on each tab in jquery-steps form. This will "Save" data on the form and stay on the same tab rather than continuing to next tab. Is it possible to add a new button to do this? Basically my each tab will have three buttons viz. Previous, Save, Save and Continue.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I dont think theres anything like that, I myself added my own Save buttons to each step to save that part of the form.